# How to find string in CSV file and replace cell with new value?

Tags: python, file, csv, replace

I have a CSV file of NBA statistical data that I'm pulling from an API, but the way they list home and away games doesn't play well with what I'm doing. I would love to be able to replace the entire cell value in a column that has the character '@' with 'AWAY' and 'vs.' with 'HOME'. Is there a way to write a short python script to accomplish this?

[image: Example data]

For a cell value that has 'BOS vs. PHI' I'd like it to be changed to 'HOME'.

For a cell value that has 'BOS @ PHI' I'd like it to be changed to 'AWAY'.

Comment: You should use `pandas` instead of messing with the raw CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df['LOCATION'] = 'HOME'
df.LOCATION[df.MATCHUP.str.contains('@')] = 'AWAY'

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       MATCHUP LOCATION
0  BOS vs. PHI     HOME
1  GSW vs. OKC     HOME
2    OKC @ GSW     AWAY
3    PHI @ BOS     AWAY
4    ATL @ NYK     AWAY
```

To replace the values within the 'MATCHUP' column, use this instead:

```
df.MATCHUP[df.MATCHUP.str.contains('@')] = 'AWAY'
df.MATCHUP[df.MATCHUP.str.contains('vs.')] = 'HOME'

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  MATCHUP
0    HOME
1    HOME
2    AWAY
3    AWAY
4    AWAY
```

Comment: I keep getting the error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: You need to call ``.str`` on a specific column, not the entire data frame.